# Is it a good idea to put "try...except..." at the first line of the code to catch unknown error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I've already handled some exceptions in my code, but I'm afraid of some unexpected errors that may occur. Let's say the code needs to finish three tasks. Is it okay to write it like this?

```
#Python 3.x

try:                 
    try:
        Task1()
    except KnownError1:
        Handler1()
    Task2()        # The second task is safe 
    try:
        Task3()
    except KnownError2:
        Handler2()   
except Exception:
    Handler3()
```

or should I catch the unknown error every time when I catch other errors:

```
try:
    Task1()
except KnownError1:
    Handler1()
except Exception:
    Handler3()
Task2()       
try:
    Task3()
except KnownError2:
    Handler2()
except Exception:
    Handler3()
```

and why?

Comment: Can you reliably recover from *any* exception in `Handler3`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's not really recovering anything. It's just some finish-off code.

Comment: In your second scenario, you continue with `Task2` (after your finish-off code) if `Task1` fails due to an unknown exception. If that makes sense, then do that. If you want to abort the process if a task fails for an unknown reason, then do that.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, but I think the second one would be difficult to manage and probably I need to write `Handler3` in many forms.

Comment: Unknown exceptions should be handled only if you want your code to behave gracefully. If not you should feel free to raise it since it is not excepted and let the caller decide how to handle the exception.
And if you want your code to behave gracefully it makes sense you use the first approach and put a exception handling at the top of the code

Answer (score 0):

In general it's never a good practice to except every exception.

But, if it make sense, in my opinion the first one is cleaner.

Comment: In this case, I need to do some finish-off work if any error occurs. Thus, it becomes necessary for me to except every potential exception if possible